# wpf datagrid datepicker change based on calculate dates again bind same column issue

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I am new to WPF. I have one scenario. For the main page, I used Datagrid with DataGridTemplateColumn with datepicker. When I change the date, I open another window, get data from relevant dates, calculate the amount, and bind the amount and dates again on the main page datagrid.

here is my code main page (Txtstartdt_SelectedDateChanged --> Datagrid->DataGridTemplateColumn -> Datepicker)

```
private void Txtstartdt_SelectedDateChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
     DateTime Startdates = (DateTime)((System.Windows.Controls.DatePicker)((object)sender)).SelectedDate;

     MessageBoxResult mesbox = System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("refresh rates and check warnings?", "Message", System.Windows.MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
                                   
    if (mesbox == MessageBoxResult.OK)
    {
       objBIt.OldStartDate = OldStartDateVal;
       objBIt.OldNetunit = objBIt.Netunit;
       objBIt.NewStartDate = Startdates;
       RefreshRates objref = new RefreshRates(loginusername, this,"bookingItinerary");
      objref.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Here is code for Another Page

```
 private void btnConfirm_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           BkingItemsRefreshrates.ToList().ForEach(x =>
           {
             x.StartDate = x.NewStartDate;
             days = (x.NtsDays != null) ? Convert.ToInt32(x.NtsDays) : 0;
             x.Enddate = x.StartDate.AddDays(days);
             x.IsRefreshed = true;
             x.Day = x.StartDate.DayOfWeek.ToString();
             x.Netunit = x.NewNetunit.ToString();
             x.NewNetUnitNotinSupptbl = (x.NewNetUnitNotinSupptbl == true) ? true : false;
             if (x.RefreshRateEditedflag == true)
             {
                CommonValues.Grossnetcalculation(x);
             }
         });

        IwParWindowre.BookingItemsitin = BkingItemsRefreshrates; //Main page observable collection assisgned.
       // IwParWindowre.ReteriveBookingItems();                    
       this.Close();
}
```

The problem is, when binding with the main page, multiple dates, and units bind, Continuously I get a message box and redirect to another page.  how to solve this...

Thanks